# Angular 4 Accessing elements from another component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create side-nav and toolbar. I want to create separate components for each so I have created 2 different components

code for `<app-sidenavmenu>`

```
<md-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
    <md-sidenav mode="push" class="sidenav" opened="false" #sidenav>
        <md-list>
            <md-list-item>...</md-list-item>
        </md-list>
    </md-sidenav>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

and code for `<app-toolbar>`

```
<md-toolbar>
    <span><button md-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()"><md-icon>menu</md-icon></button></span>
    <span><h2>App name</h2></span>
</md-toolbar>
```

and in third home component I am using above components

Now I wanted to access `#sidenav` from side-nav component to toolbar component so that side-nav will be toggle with toggle function

How to achieve this.

Comment: refer to this link to learn more about component interaction https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to have the AppComponent manage the state of the sidebar. It has an object that both the sidebar and the navbar have a reference too. The navbar changes it and the sidebar will response.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <my-navbar  [state]="state"></my-navbar>
    <my-sidebar [state]="state"></my-sidebar>
  `
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  state = {
    showSideBar: true;
  };
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-navbar',
  template: `
    <div>
      <span class="toggle" (click)="toggleSideBar()">Toggle</span> Navbar
    </div>
  `
})
export class NavBar implements OnInit {
  @Input() state: any;

  toggleSideBar() {
    this.state.showSideBar = !this.state.showSideBar;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-sidebar',
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="state.showSideBar">SideBar</div>
  `
})
export class SideBar implements OnInit {
  @Input() state: any;
}
```

Here's a plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/ldpG25?p=preview

An alternative is to have a service that keeps track of the navbar state for you. It would be a pretty simple service but would require the use of an Subject. Subjects are kind of like events, so your Navbar would call the service to emit the toggle, and the SideBar would subscribe to the service and get the toggle pushed to it.

Hopefully that makes sense, feel free to ask questions!

Answer (score 1):

you can create input variable in sidebar and pass its value from your third component and toggle its value in the toolbar and out put it to parent(third) which will reflect change in sidebar.

> third.component.html

```
<md-sidenav-container [sidebarState]="sidebarState" class="sidenav-container">
    <md-sidenav mode="push" class="sidenav" opened="sidebarState" #sidenav>
        <md-list>
            <md-list-item>...</md-list-item>
        </md-list>
    </md-sidenav>
</md-sidenav-container>

<md-toolbar (change)="toggle()">
    <span><button md-button ><md-icon>menu</md-icon></button></span>
    <span><h2>App name</h2></span>
</md-toolbar>
```

> third.component.ts

```
export class ThirdComponent{
private sidebarState: boolean = false;


toggle(){
this.sidebarState = !this.sidebarState;
}
```

> sidebar.component.ts

```
export class SidebarComponent {
@Input() sidebarState: boolean;

}
```

> toolbar.component.ts

```
export class ToolbarComponent {
    @Output() change: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

someEvent() {
this.change.emit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new Service.
Shared between both components and hide/show sidenav if, for example, function isOpened is true. Also you can create in the service an EventEmitter and subscribe this in the sidenav conmponent.

Answer (score 0):

You can first add an output to get the event:
First import them:

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

after that in the class:

```
@Output() sidenavToggle = new EventEmitter();
```

in toogle function:

```
toggle(){
 this.sidenavToggle.emit();
}
```

In the component directly or calling other function from main component:

```
<app-toolbar (sidenavToggle)="sidenav.toggle()"></app-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created shared service for this:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class DashboardMenuService {
    private dashboardMenuToggleEventEmitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

    public toggleDashboardMenu(): void {
        this.dashboardMenuToggleEventEmitter.emit();
    }

    public subscribe(next: () => void): void {
        this.dashboardMenuToggleEventEmitter.subscribe(next);
    }
}
```